# How can I make a "greenscreen" web app?

Tags: c#, user-interface, hotkeys

In informal conversations with our customer service department, they have expressed dissatisfaction with our web-based CSA (customer service application). In a callcenter, calls per hour are critical, and lots of time is wasted mousing around, clicking buttons, selecting values in dropdown lists, etc. What the dirrector of customer service has wistfully asked for is a return to the good old days of keyboard-driven applications with very little visual detail, just what's necessary to present data to the CSR and process the call.

I can't help but be reminded of the greenscreen apps we all used to use (and the more seasoned among us used to make). Not only would such an application be more productive, but healthier for the reps to use, as they must be risking injury doing data entry through a web app all day.

I'd like to keep the convenience of browser-based deployment and preserve our existing investment in the Microsoft stack, but how can I deliver this keyboard-driven [ultra-simple greenscreen concept](http://www.coboloncogs.org/HOME.HTM) to the web?

Good answers will link to libraries, other web applications with a similar style, best practices for organizing and prioritizing keyboard shortcut data (not how to add them, but how to store and maintain the shortcuts and automatically resolve conflicts, etc.

**EDIT: accepted answers will not be mini-lectures on how to do UI on the web. I do not want any links, buttons or anything to click on whatsoever.**

**EDIT2: this application has 500 users, spread out in call centers around North America. I cannot retrain them all to use the TAB key**

Comment: You've got your requirements, but the description of the issue says to me that the application has poorly implemented UI.

Comment: Would you say SO has a poorly-implemented UI? Now try and use it keyboard-only for 8 hours a day and get back to me. Developing productive and ergonomic browser-based callcenter apps is a real challenge!

Comment: Are Silverlight or Flash options for you?  It seems to me they might be along the lines of what you're looking for.

Comment: @rexem is right (you stated as much by implying the director didn't like it).  Comparing SO to your site is not exactly apples to apples.  It is a challenge to develop quality apps in general and your user acceptance testing rejected version 1.0 of the UI.  Don't allow the web app concept to die, just make it better.

Comment: I'm not killing the web app concept, but that does explain the argumentative "answers" I'm getting.

Comment: Has CSS tabindex been considered?  Using the tab button to navigate forms has been consistently used, then it becomes a matter of user training.  Mind that some people don't want to work faster, and it's not the applications fault.

Comment: LOL: "I want a keyboard centric app, but I won't support tabbing through fields"

Comment: I didn't say I won't support it, I said I cannot rely on training to enforce it. Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: It's the least I can do after you feebly try to put words in my mouth about SO UI ;)

Comment: What is it about this annoying trend on SO lately? Rather than answering a question, people want to talk the questioner out of an approach based on the little bit of context they glean from the question. The question is not "Should I create a green screen style app?" /rant over.

Comment: "Rather than answering a question, people want to talk the questioner out of an approach based on the little bit of context they glean from the question."

I have noticed this on most other forums, and it's sneaking into SO. I feel the same exact way. It's very frustrating to be talked out of an approach you didn't ask for opinions on.

Comment: If you don't like the answers then you can down vote them.  If someone asks how to do something that is patently absurd and not a good idea (not speaking about this in particular) then you should tell them that.  If the community agrees then they will up vote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I had to use some of those apps over time, will give my feedback as a user, FWIW, and maybe it helps you to help your users :-) Sorry it's a bit long but the topic is rather close to my heart - as I had myself to prototype the "improved" interface for such a system (which, according to our calculations, saves *very* nontrivial amounts of money and avoids the user dissatisfaction) and then lead the team that implemented it.

There is one common issue that I noticed with quite a few of CRMs: there is 20+ fields on the screen, of which typically one uses 4-5 for performing of 90% of operations. But one needs to click through the unnecessary fields anyway.

I might be wrong with this assumption, of course (as in my case there was a wide variety of users with different functions using the system). But do try to sit down with the users and see how they are using the application and see if you can optimize something UI-wise - or, if really it's a matter of not knowing how to use "TAB" (and they *really* need to use each and every of those 20 fields each time) - you will be able to coach a few of them and check whether this  is something sufficient for them - and then roll out the training for the entire organization. Ensure you have the intuitive hotkey support, and that if a list contains 2000 items, the users do not have to scroll it manually to find the right one, but rather can use FF's feature to select the item by typing the start of its text.

You might learn a lot by looking at the usage patterns of the application and then optimizing the UI accordingly. If you have multiple organizational functions that use the system - then the "ideal UI" for each of them might be different, so the question of which to implement, and if, becomes a business decision.

There are also some other little details that matter for the users - sometimes what you'd thought would be the main input field for them in reality is not - and they have an empty textarea eating up half of the screen, while they have to enter the really important data into a small text field somewhere in the corner. Or that in their screen resolution they need the horizontal scrolling (or, scrolling at all).

Again, sitting down with the users and observing should reveal this.

One more issue: "Too fast developer hardware" phenomenon: A lot of the web developers tend to use large displays with high resolution, showing the output of a very powerful PCs. When the result is shown on the CSR's laptop screen at 1024x768 of a year-old laptop, the layout looks quite different from what was anticipated, as well as the rendering performance. Tune, tune, tune.

And, finally - if your organization is geographically disperse, *always* test with the longest-latency/smallest bandwidth link equivalent. These issues are not seen when doing the testing locally, but add a lot of annoyance when using the system over the WAN. In short - try to use the worst-case scenario when doing any testing/development of your application - then this will become annoying to you and you will optimize its use - so then the users that are in better situation will jump in joy over the apps performance.

If you are in for the "green screen app" - then maybe for the power users provide a single long text input field where they could type all the information in the CLI-type fashion and just hit "submit" **or** the ENTER key (though this design decision is not something to be taken lightly as it is a lot of work). But everyone needs to realize that "green-screen" applications have a rather steep learning curve - this is another factor to consider from the business point of view, along with the attrition rate, etc. Ask the boss how long does the typical agent stay at the same place and how would the productivity be affected if they needed a 3-month term to come to full speed. :) There's a balance that is not decided by the programmers alone, nor by the management alone, but requires a joint effort.

And finally a side note in case you have "power users": you might want to take a look at [conkeror](http://conkeror.org/) as a browser - though fairly slow in itself, it looks quite flexible in what it can offer from the keyboard-only control perspective.

Comment: +1 for the too fast dev hardware. I had my workstation downgraded for just this reason. we were running javascript too fast :)

Comment: I can only thank you very much on behalf of your users :-) kudos!

Answer (score 11):

I make web based CSR apps. What your manager is forgetting is now the application is MUCH more complex. We are asking more from our reps than we did 15 years ago. We collect more information and record more data than before.

Instead of a "greenscreen" application, you should focus on making the web application behave better. For example,dont have a dropdown for year when it can be a input field. Make sure the taborder is correct and sane, you can even put little numbers next to each field grouping to indicate tab order. Assign different screens/tabs to F keys and denote them on the screen.

You should be able to use your web app without a mouse at all with no loss of productivity if done correctly.

Leverage the use of AJAX so a round trip to the server doesn't change the focus of their cursor.

On a CSR app, you often have several defaults. you should assign each default a button and allow the csr to push 1 button to get the default they want. this will reduce the amount of clicking and mousing around.

**Also very important** You need to sit with the CSR's and watch them for a while to get a feel for how they use the app. if you haven't done this, you are probably overlooking simple changes that will greatly enhance their productivity.

Comment: Trapping function keys might be an issue due to different browsers behaving differently. Check http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html as there are some details regarding this there.

Comment: Can you give some more specific and less subjective advice? Perhaps some links to best practices documents or examples of keyboard-driven web applications?

Comment: +1 for sitting with users.  It's the simplest thing you can do -- find the power users and see where they fail.  If they can't use it "out of the box," you need to change it.

Comment: @Buggabill: The multi-browser issue may be non-existent if the call center has a tightly controlled software architecture. (In other words, chances are good -- if it's like call centers I've seen -- that all the browsers are identical, and you're coding to a single predictable environment.)

Answer (score 5):

```
body { background: #000; color: #0F0; }
```

More seriously, it's entirely possible to bind keyboard shortcuts to actions in a web app.

You might consider teaching your users to just use the Tab key - that's how I fill out most web forms. Tab to a select list and type out the first few letters of the option I'm attempting to select.  If the page doesn't do goofy things with structure and tabindexes, I can usually fill out most web forms with just the keyboard.

Comment: The problem with a lot of users is that the mouse actually works in these apps.  The only thing that you could do is unplug the mice from their computers, because if the mouse is there, they will use it.  Guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

I can't agree with the others more when they say the first priority of the redesign should be going and talking to / observing your users and see where they have problems. I think you would see far more ROI if you find out the most common tasks and the most common errors your users make and streamline those *within* the bounds of your existing UI. I realize this isn't an easy thing to do, but if you can pull it off you'll have much happier users (since you've solved their workflow issues) and much happier bosses (since you saved the company money by not having to re-train all the users on a completely new UI).

After reading everyone else's answers and comments, I wanted to address a few other things:

> **EDIT: accepted answers will not be mini-lectures on how to do UI on the web. I do not want any links, buttons or anything to click on whatsoever.**

I don't mean to be argumentative, but this sounds like you've already made up your mind without having thought of the implications on the users. I can immediately see a couple pitfalls with this approach:

- A greenscreen-esque UI may *not* be
  more productive for your users. For
  example, what's the average age of
  your users? Most people 25 and
  younger have had little to no
  exposure to these types of UIs.
  Suddenly imposing this sort of
  interface on them could cause a
  **major** backlash from your users. As an example, look at what happened
  when Facebook decided to change its
  UI to the "stream" concept - huge
  outrage from the users!
- The web wasn't really designed with this sort of interface in mind. What I mean is that people are not used to having command-line-like interfaces when they visit a website. They expect visual medium (images, buttons, links, etc.) in addition to text. Changing too drastically from this could confuse your users.
- Programming this type of interface will be tough. As in my last point, the web doesn't play well with command-line-like or text-only interfaces. Things like function keys, keyboard shortcuts (like ctrl- and alt-) are all poorly and inconsistently supported which means you'll have to come up with your own ways of accessing standard things like help (since F1 will map to the web browser's help, not your app's).

> **EDIT2: this application has 500 users, spread out in call centers around North America. I cannot retrain them all to use the TAB key**

I think this argument is really just a strawman. If you are introducing a wholly new UI, you're going to have to train your users on it. Really, it should be assumed that *any* change to your UI will require training in one form or another. Something simple like adding tab-navigation to the UI is actually comparatively small in the training department. If you did this it would be very easy to send out a "handy new feature in the UI" email, or even better, have some sort of "tip of the day" (that users can toggle off, of course) which tells them about cool timesaving features like tab navigation.

I can't speak for the other posters here, but I did want to say that I hope you don't think we're being too argumentative here as that's not our (well OK, *my*) intent. Rather the reaction comes from us hearing the idea for your UI and not being convinced that it is necessarily the best thing for your users. You are fully welcome to say I'm wrong and that this is what your users will benefit most from; but before you do, just remember that at the end of the day it's your users who matter most and if they don't buy in to your new UI, no one will.

Answer (score 0):

It's really more of a keyboard-centric mentality when developing.  I use the keyboard for as much as possible and the apps I build tend to show that (so **I** can quickly go through my use cases).

Something as simple as getting the tab order correct could be all your app needs (I guess I'm not sure if you can set this in ASP.NET...).  A lot of controls will auto-complete for the rest.